# Get Cards for Videos from Youtube APIs

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to get a list of all cards associated with a video id. I've looked at the different Youtube APIs, but no success. 
[example of cards in a video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBjBE.jpg)

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by Youtube API. You can find the supported methods by Youtube API in this [reference list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - this is only a partial answer.

It is possible to get card stats for a given channel through the Reporting API.
To do so, you need to create a reporting job https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports#video-cards

This will give you basic stats (**card_id included**) for every card of every video for one channel during the specified time interval. At this stage, we know that there are cards for a given video, we know what type of cards these are, and we have some basic stats regarding their performance. **We still don't know what is behind that card**.

So the follow up question is: how to query youtube APIs with a card_id to retrieve more detail information about that card? 
If someone knows this, then we have a way of getting card infos for any video.